# Swapping highest and lowest values in a single array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, swap

I'm new to PHP. A friend was helping me learn this, but he's not available for a while. I know some things may simply not make sense (i'm learning, and I know this isn't exactly a beginners function).

GOAL:
1. Find highest and lowest value within the array ($lemons).
2. Switch the placement of said values. (IE: 6, 2, 7, 8, 0, 9 --> 6, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0).

### Thanks!

```
 <?php
 function switcheroo($lemons) {
    $min_lemons = min($lemons);
    $max_lemons = max($lemons);
    foreach ($lemons as $key => $value) {
        if ($max_lemons > 0) {
            $max_decoy = $min_lemons;
        }
        if ($min_lemons < 0) {
            $min_decoy = $max_lemons;
        }
    }
    return $lemons;
 }
 $lemons = array(6, 2, 7, 8, 0, 9);
 print_r(switcheroo($lemons));
 ?>
```

Comment: Nice to help someone with their homework. If your really want to learn something, the best way is to try to figure it out yourself, as this is a quite basic question, and you almost have the solution yourself.

Comment: Have a look at the sort function to get it in order and then swap the values of the first and last value

Comment: @John, Thanks! I've been really trying... I understand that I need to put the values inside the array, rather than replacing them directly. However, I just keep repeating/undoing the same things, like:

     '$min_lemons = min($lemons); 
     $max_lemons = max($lemons);
     $min_lemons = $max_lemons;
     $max_lemons = $min_lemons;
     = brilliant logic :/'

chrisbulmer, I would like to do that, but it was a challenge to do it this way. He knew it was going to be hard, and wasn't going to have me do it this way right off that bat, but I insisted. Ooops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the most elegant solution, but it works as intended:

```
$arr = array(6, 2, 7, 8, 0, 9);

echo 'Array before: <br /><pre>', print_r($arr, true);

function switcheroo($array) {
    $new_array = $array;

    $min_lemons = min($new_array);
    $max_lemons = max($new_array);

    $min_lemons_key = array_search($min_lemons, $new_array);
    $max_lemons_key = array_search($max_lemons, $new_array);

    $new_array[$min_lemons_key] = $max_lemons;
    $new_array[$max_lemons_key] = $min_lemons;

    return $new_array;
}

echo 'Array after: <br />', print_r(switcheroo($arr), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out.. I'm not the greatest at PHP but I found this interesting!

```
<?php
$array = array(3,6,12,7,3,6);
print_r($array);

$max = max($array);
$min = min($array);
$maxKey = array_search($max, $array);
$minKey = array_search($min, $array);

$array[$maxKey] = $min;
$array[$minKey] = $max;

echo '<br />';
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this it's best not to use the `foreach` syntax since you're not using associative arrays, it makes working with the array more difficult, and it doesn't really teach you much. A simple `for` loop is best in a situation like this, as well as being a cross-language staple.

```
// prepare the lemons.
$lemons = array(6, 2, 7, 8, 0, 9);
print_r($lemons);

// initialize these values to assume that the first element is
// both the max and min as the initial basis for comparison.
$cur_max = $lemons[0];
$cur_max_index = 0;
$cur_min = $lemons[0];
$cur_min_index = 0;

// iterate through the array
for( $i=0; $i<count($lemons); $i++ ) {
    if( $lemons[$i] > $cur_max ) {
        $cur_max = $lemons[$i];
        $cur_max_index = $i;
    } else if( $lemons[$i] < $cur_min ) {
        $cur_min = $lemons[$i];
        $cur_min_index = $i;
    }
}

// do the swap. I am ignoring the fact that we already have the
// max/min values to illustrate a 'proper' swap.
$temp_val = $lemons[$cur_min_index];
$lemons[$cur_min_index] = $lemons[$cur_max_index];
$lemons[$cur_max_index] = $temp_val;

print_r($lemons);
```

While you're learning the basics of programming you should try to avoid using 'helper' functions like `min()` and `max()`. The point of the exercise is, ostensibly, to get you familiar with the array and logical operations necessary to begin writing a basic sorting algorithm.

Comment: Wow, just looking at this (it makes perfect sense) shows me that I need to read/study more before I tackle such examples. I know I wouldn't be able to do that on my own. Thanks!